# Is there a way to mention a line in a comment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to mention/quote a line inside a comment?

Example:

```
public int sum(int a,int b){
//return sum of a,b
return a+b;  //(line 3)
}

public int sumplus2(int a, int b){
// same calc of line 3 but summing up 2 to the result
return sum(a,b) + 2;
}
```

Is there a way to, when I click in **"line 1"** on the second comment, the cursor go straight to the line 1, like a goto but within comments?

Or, better yet, is there a better way of doing the same idea?

Comment: No, but you can place the cursor on "sum" and press F12...

Comment: This is an IDE feature not a C# feature.

Comment: Whoever voted to close because "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic", please note the explanation for that particular reason has a rather specific exemption that applies to this question: "_**unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.**_".

Comment: For VS the closest is at the type level: `/// I like waffles <see cref="Must.BeFullyQualified.TypeName" />` which you can interact with as if it were inline (i.e. goto definition).

Comment: So every time you add or remove a line the comments are out of date and need updating?

Comment: By the way, a comment like `// same calc of line 3 but summing up 2 to the result` is redundant and just pollutes your source code with noise. The comment doesn't add anything. It just says what the code line beneath is doing. But what it does is obvious by just looking at the code line itself and doesn't need a comment. It is a bit like writing (i am exaggering a bit) `int v = 5; // Assigns 5 to the variable v` -- "_no shit sherlock, without the comment i would have never understood..._" Add comments where they help understanding. (1/2)

Comment: Trying to make smarter/better comments seems like a poor substitute for making smarter/better code.

Comment: (2/2) Don't explain code lines in comments, explain what the purposes of methods, code blocks, fields, variables, etc. are as far as they are not _blatantly_ and _instantly_ obvious by looking at the code lines. (Comments are also commonly used for generating documentation/intellisense tips, but this is a somewhat bigger topic...)

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I somewhat knew that this way of thinking was not ideal. Props to @AlexK. to at least trying to come to something close to the question.

Comment: You could use the standard xml comments for the methods and reference `sum` from the `sumplus2` comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such feature built into c# or Visual Studio (/Code) exists to do that. You'd need to write your own extension to VS (/Code) to make that feature.